# RxJava сортировка списка по одну из эллементов

Tags: android, массивы, rxjava, rxandroid

Имею json из такими строками как `title`, `time`, `click_url`, `img`, `type`, `top` и тд.
Я получаю список эллеметов со строками которые я описал выше.
Мне нужно Получить список эллеметов который будет иметь одинаковый тип

```
model.getType().equals("FAVOURITE")
```

а все прочие эллементы не должны попасть в этот список.

Я пробовал и `Maybe` и `.map` и `.flatmap` и `.filter` и `.skip()` и `.contains` пока что безуспешно.

Вот модель

```
public class Model {
    @SerializedName("title")
    private String title;

    @SerializedName("type")
    private String type;

    @SerializedName("img")
    private String img;

    @SerializedName("click_url")
    private String click_url;

    @SerializedName("time")
    private String time;


    public Model(String title, String img, String click_url, String time, String type) {
        this.title = title;
        this.type = type;
        this.img = img;
        this.click_url = click_url;
        this.time = time;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public String getImg() {
        return img;
    }

    public String getClick_url() {
        return click_url;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }
}
```

вот rxjava кусок кода

```
    private final CompositeDisposable disposable = new CompositeDisposable();
 private void fetchData() {
        disposable.add(iGetterJSON.getList()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .map(unsortedList -> {
                    List<Model> sortedList = new ArrayList<>(unsortedList.size());
                    Collections.copy(sortedList, unsortedList);
                    Collections.sort(sortedList, new Model.MyComparator());
                    return sortedList;
                })
                .subscribe((Consumer<List<Model>>) this::initRecyclerView));
    }
```

интерфейс для Retrofit2

```
@GET("/")
Observable<List<Model>> getList();
```

Мой компаратор но как мне получить имменно тот список что мне нада я так и не понял(

```
public static class MyComparator implements Comparator<Model> {

        @Override
        public int compare(Model model, Model t1) {
            if (model.getType().equals(TYPE_FAVOURITES)){
                return 1;
            } else if (model.getType().equals(TYPE_STORIES)){
                return 2;
            } else if (model.getType().equals(TYPE_VIDEO)){
                return 3;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам надо поменять данные в источнике данных. Для этого есть оператор `map`. В нём можно стандартными средствами отсортировать список. Примерно так:

```
.map { list ->
   Collections.sort(list, Comparator { c1, c2 -> c1.type.compareTo(c2.type) })
}
```

Comment: это что похожое что и в этом вопросе https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40267383/android-rxjava-sort-list-with-comparator-class но проблема в том что тогда в операторе `.subscribe` я немогу получить список для своего adapter

Comment: Почему не можете? По факту ничего не меняется - данные остаются того же типа, просто их порядок поменялся. Возможно, вам стоит подробнее описать возникшую проблему.

Comment: Смотри у меня есть моделька со строками `title, time, click_url, img, type, top`. Я в операторе `.subscribe` я получаю список со всеми эллементами которые у меня есть. МНЕ НУЖНО отсортировать список так чтобы убрать от туда все остальные эллементы кроме тех которые не равны этому выражению `model.getType().equals("FAVOURITE")` как это можно сделать?

Comment: Значит вам нужно отфильтровать. Например цикл в map пустить.

Comment: я Вас правильно понял, в операторе .map к списку применить .filter и отфильтровать. Компаратор в таком случае мне не нужен.

Comment: `.map(list->{list.stream(что сюда передать).filter(и что сюда?) return list;})`

Comment: Кажется в этом вопросе есть мой ответ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13138990/how-to-search-in-a-list-of-java-object

Comment: Там совсем не про rx, скорее это ваш ответ: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48685427/15923106